# Render datetime dates from database and put into array with Enumerator

Tags: c#, datetime, enumerator

I'm trying to make an availability calendar showing reserved dates and need to render the reserved dates. 
In my database I've got `arivalDate` and a `Leavingdate`.
Now what I'm trying to do is:

- get `arivalDate` and `Leavingdate`
- put the dates between `arivalDate` and `leavingDate` in array for all rows in database

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcnx"].ToString());
    string sql = "select * from bookings";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
    conn.Open();

    MySqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

    for (int i = 0; i <= dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        string arival = (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString());
        string leaving = (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString());
        string id = (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());

        DateTime dateArive = DateTime.Parse(arival);
        DateTime dateLeave = DateTime.Parse(leaving);

        List<DateTime> datesList = new List<DateTime>();
        for (DateTime evalDate = dateArive; evalDate < dateLeave; evalDate = evalDate.AddDays(1.0))
        {
            datesList.Add(evalDate);
        }
    }
    string testing = "";
    IEnumerator<DateTime> ien = datesList.GetEnumerator();
    while (ien.MoveNext())
    {
        testing += (ien.Current).ToString("dd M yy") + " <br />";
    }

    lbltst.Text = testing;
}
```

I keep getting errors no matter what I try. Can somebody please help?

Comment: give the details of errors you get and which line you get the error.

Comment: I don't that will compile, You need to declare datesList outside the loop, or move the test enumeration inside the loop

Comment: Thank you James Barrass that works :D (moved datesList outside)

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `datesList` outside the loop, or move the test enumeration inside the loop

Comment: Thanks James, i would give you a vote up but my reputation does not allow it :(